# Syntax error, telling me it wants ; and several other things

Tags: java, eclipse

Just trying to run through some code for an assignment I'm doing. It is probably simple but for the life of me I can't figure out why I get the above error at the first line

```
(public WaterLog.......).
```

Later I want to pass it this line:

```
[ log = new WaterLog(8, damCapacity); ]
```

Any help would be appreciated, I am new to this sorry.

```
public class WaterLog(Integer windowSize, Integer maxEntry) {

private Integer size = windowSize;
private Integer max = maxEntry;
private ArrayList theLog(int windowSize);
private int counter = 0;


public void addEntry(Integer newEntry) throws SimulationException {

    theLog.add(0, newEntry);
    counter++;

}

public Integer getEntry(Integer index) throws SimulationException {

    If (thelog.isEmpty() || thelog.size() < index) {
        return null;
    }
    return thelog.get(index);

}

public Integer variation() throws SimulationException {

    int old, recent = 0;
    recent = thelog.get(0);
    old = thelog.get(thelog.size-1);
    return recent-old;
}

public Integer numEntries() {

    return counter;

}

}
```

Comment: a method cannot contains other methods.. maybe you mean public class WaterLog ?

Comment: Is `WaterLog` a class or method?

Comment: Its not a class declaration and not a constructor and not a method. What is this?

Comment: you have mixed up class,const together

Comment: Yes it is a class, I edited that sorry.

Comment: It's not a valid syntax for a class. public class WaterLog(Integer windowSize, Integer maxEntry) {

Comment: Always quote the *exact* error message -- don't paraphrase.  And indicate which line was flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `SimulationException` is defined correctly:

```
class WaterLog{

private Integer size;
private Integer max ;
private ArrayList<Integer> theLog; //parameterize your lists
private int counter = 0;

public WaterLog(Integer windowSize, Integer maxEntry) //this is the behavior you were    looking for
{
this.size = windowSize;
this.max = maxEntry;
theLog = new ArrayList<Integer>(windowSize);
}

public void addEntry(Integer newEntry) throws SimulationException {

theLog.add(0, newEntry);
counter++;

}

public Integer getEntry(Integer index) throws SimulationException {

if (theLog.isEmpty() || theLog.size() < index) { //Java is case sensitive
    return null;
}
return theLog.get(index);

}

public Integer variation() throws SimulationException {

int old, recent = 0;
recent = theLog.get(0);
old = theLog.get(theLog.size()-1); //again, watch case, also size is a method
return recent-old;
}

public Integer numEntries() {

return counter;

}

}
```

See the comments I added.

**EDIT:** To explain a bit further what was going on, let's take a look at what you were doing.

```
public class WaterLog(Integer windowSize, Integer maxEntry) {

private Integer size = windowSize;
private Integer max = maxEntry;
private ArrayList theLog(int windowSize);
private int counter = 0;
```

You seem to have confused a class with a constructor. The variables you defined were attributes, which was correct. You needed to use the syntax I showed in my answer to create a constructor. For that same reason, you don't have access to variables like `windowSize`. To remedy this, we allow them to still be *defined* outside the constructor, but *assigned values* inside it, where we have access to `windowSize` and `maxEntry`.

Comment: @Takendarkk Well alright, the stuff with the constructor was pretty egregious, but I can try...

Comment: Ya, I'm glad you are doing it because I don't know where to start.

Comment: @Takendarkk There, did my best.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some parameters to this class you need a constructor. By default Each and EVERY class comes with a default constructor - which is there, you just don't see it ( but can declare it). What you can then do is make an overloaded construcotr ( which takes some arguments ) and this is what you want so..

if you have a class

```
class WaterLog {
    // no constructor
}
```

the above is really a

```
class WaterLog {
   public WaterLog() {
      // this is the constructor - if you do not declare it its still here, you just dont see it. Ofcourse you have option to declare it.
   }
}
```

The overloaded constructor is something like this

```
class WaterLog {
   public WaterLog() {
     //default constructor
   }
   public WaterLog(Integer int, String string, etc...) {
     //overloaded constructor
   }
}
```

and the above is what you need in order to pass arguments to this class constructor. I am not briliant at explaining things but if you need more clarification just let me know :)