# Unhandled exception type SimulationException

Tags: java, eclipse

My question is why I am still getting a Unhandled exception type `SimulationExcpetion` on calling `damOverflowed()` when that isn't declared in the interface for that method. The `levelTooLow method is declared in the interface and in the class and is fine. I added the interface methods at the bottom if that helps.

```
package asgn1Solution;

import asgn1Question.SimulationException;
import asgn1Question.Log;
import asgn1Question.Actions;

public class DamActions implements Actions{

    private Integer capacity;
    private Integer nomRelease;
    private Integer duration;
    private Log logging;

public DamActions(Integer damCapacity, Integer defaultRelease, Integer jobDuration, WaterLog damLog) {
    capacity = damCapacity;
    nomRelease = defaultRelease;
    duration = jobDuration;
    logging = damLog;

}

    public boolean levelTooLow() throws SimulationException {
        if (logging.getEntry(0) < capacity*.25) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean damOverflowed()  {
        if (logging.getEntry(0) > capacity) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**In Actions.java** 
 :

```
public boolean levelTooLow() throws SimulationException;
public boolean damOverflowed();
```

Comment: you should handle exception, either by throwing it again in the calling method, or using `try catch` block

Comment: The throws notion only enforces you to handle that exception by yourself. Missing throws declaration does not mean that this method will not throw it under special circumstances...

Comment: Does `Log#getEntry(int)` declare that it throws `SimulationException`?

Comment: @JonK it doesn't have to

Comment: Are you sure that this code compiles and you are not executing a previous version of your own code?

Comment: @JonK It doesn't. You can see there is neither a try-catch nor a `throws` in `damOverflowed`. If `getEntry()` would throw it, `damOverflowed` had to handle it because it is a _checked exception_

Comment: @ifLoop It just seems strange that `levelTooLow()` declares that it throws that exception without ever throwing it - unless it's actually thrown by the `Log#getEntry(int)` call. In which case, there'd be a compile error in `damOverflowed()` because it hasn't been handled.

Comment: @mangusta No, it doesn't *have to*, but if it does declare it then it needs to be handled. See my answer.

Comment: @JohnK the method does not necessarily need to include an exception-throwing method in order to throw an exception. if `levelTooLow()` throws exception, it does not mean that the exception occurs in `getEntry()`

Comment: @mangusta No it doesn't, but we can clearly see from the code that was posted that `damOverflowed` doesn't explicitly throw any exceptions itself. That being the case, the only way you'd get a compilation error about an unhandled `SimulationException` is if a method called within `damOverflowed` declared that it throws the exception. Also, as there is only one method called within `damOverflowed`, that must be where the exception is coming from. See the link at the start of my answer, it contains the code for `getEntry`.

Comment: @JonK why you complicate things? the author did not post all his codes, probably some method just calls `levelTooLow()` without `try-catch` block and without further exception throw. i think he simply mistaken and thinks that it is `damOverflowed()` throws an exception, while in reality `levelTooLow()` does that.

Comment: @mangusta The OP's question is "why I am still getting a Unhandled exception type SimulationExcpetion on calling `damOverflowed()`?". Why are you bringing `levelTooLow()` into this? It isn't relevant in any way, which should be painfully obvious because they've posted *the entire method body of `damOverflowed()`*.

Comment: @JonK see the second sentence of my prev.message :D

Comment: @mangusta `damOverflowed()` does not call `levelTooLow()`, so `levelTooLow()` is completely irrelevant in the context of this question. Re-read the question.

Comment: @JohK you better re-read my message again :D author mistaken and has used wrong function name in his question

Comment: @mangusta Where is your evidence or justification for that assumption?

Answer (score 0):

From [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895162/syntax-error-telling-me-it-wants-and-several-other-things), in your `WaterLog` class you have declared the following method:

```
public Integer getEntry(Integer index) throws SimulationException {

    if (thelog.isEmpty() || thelog.size() < index) {
        return null;
    }
    return thelog.get(index);
}
```

The important thing to note here is the **`throws SimulationException`** clause in the method signature. This indicates that any method that calls `getEntry` **must** either handle a `SimulationException` *or* declare that it may be thrown*.

*This isn't strictly true, if the declared exception is an *unchecked exception* (i.e. a derivative of `RuntimeException`), then you aren't forced to handle it, even if you declare it in the `throws` clause. However, that you are getting compilation errors regarding this exception indicates that `SimulationException` is a *checked exception*, so does need to be handled or declared.

Thus, you have three options. First, you can enclose your call to `getEntry` in a `try-catch` block like so:

```
public boolean damOverflowed()  {
    try {
        if (logging.getEntry(0) > capacity) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SimulationException ex) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare that `damOverflowed` can also throw that exception:

```
public boolean damOverflowed() throws SimulationException {
```

Finally, as `WaterLog#getEntry(Integer)` doesn't actually appear to ever throw that exception (despite declaring that it can), your third option is to simply remove the declaration from the method signature:

```
public Integer getEntry(Integer index) {

    if (thelog.isEmpty() || thelog.size() < index) {
        return null;
    }
    return thelog.get(index);
}
```

I would also recommend reading through the [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) tutorial from Oracle.